# Customize x-axis in Synth-function path.plot (Rstudio)

Tags: r, synth

I'm using the Synth package in R and when plotting the results (with path.plot and gaps.plot), I would like to customize the labels on the x-axis to character values like "January 2015, February 2015". Currently my time variable is numerical (1 = January 2015, 2 = February 2015 etc).

Does anybody know if there is a way to adjust the x-axis labels inside the path.plot function, OR if it's possible to put additional arguments to the plot outside the original one, in order to suppress the automatic x-labels given by path.plot?

Thank you all in advance :))

Comment: Welcome to SO! To help us to help you could you please make your issue reproducible by sharing a sample of your **data**, the **code** you tried and the **packages** you used? See [how to make a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

You can add or change labels with `Ylab = "Y Label", Xlab = "X Label"`

But I don't know how change the plot.